# Convert background image via CSS to inline styling?

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS for a hero background image:

```
#main > header {
  padding: 12em 0 10em 0 ;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Would it be possible to convert this over to an line styling scenario?

This is my HTML:

```
<header id="header" class="alt">
  <h1><a href="index.html">Spectral</a></h1>
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="special">
        <a href="#menu" class="menuToggle"><span>Menu</span></a>
        <div id="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="generic.html">Generic</a></li>
            <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The reason I need to do this is because I am converting a static HTML site over to a CMS and to manage the images I need to add certain tags. Thanks for all replies and direction with this...

Comment: Don't you just add all these css unto the `header` tag? (i.e. `<header style="padding: 12em 0 10em 0 ; ...>) or are asking a different method altogether?

Comment: @YongPin That is a solution too. However, with that the code looks hard to read or manage. Because he need to replace all the image links with some cms dynamic code I guess. <style></style> is better for that approach I think.

Comment: Doesn't really make a difference imo, you could just indent it properly and it will look the same wherever you put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use inline-style like below, you change your image path easly into dynamic

```css
header {
  padding: 12em 0 10em 0 ;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header id="header" class="alt" style='background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/yellow-crash-test-dummy-yellow-crash-test-dummy-car-seat-116968697.jpg");
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/yellow-crash-test-dummy-yellow-crash-test-dummy-car-seat-116968697.jpg");
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/yellow-crash-test-dummy-yellow-crash-test-dummy-car-seat-116968697.jpg");
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/yellow-crash-test-dummy-yellow-crash-test-dummy-car-seat-116968697.jpg");'>
  <h1><a href="index.html">Spectral</a></h1>
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="special">
        <a href="#menu" class="menuToggle"><span>Menu</span></a>
        <div id="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="generic.html">Generic</a></li>
            <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

let me know if have another issue.

Comment: Thanks - this looks like the "easiest" way of doing it and perhaps most sensible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check my approach. This way you can link the images to the CMS. You can use the style tags before or after the html.

```css
<style>
#main > header {
    padding: 12em 0 10em 0 ;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../../images/banner.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<header id="header" class="alt">
    <h1><a href="index.html">Spectral</a></h1>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="special">
                <a href="#menu" class="menuToggle"><span>Menu</span></a>
                <div id="menu">
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="generic.html">Generic</a></li>
                    <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```